# Empty json string when using json_encode function

Tags: php, mysql, json

I run into a very strange problem using json_encode() function in php. I have 2 tables with data. In table 1 there are just 2 rows. Using the code below works fine with json_encode() function. In table 2 I have 50,000 rows at the moment from which I select (for example 1000) rows. Using the same code doesn't lead me to a json string.

The code I am using is this:

```
$array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[] = $row;
}
echo count($array);
echo json_encode($array);
```

How can I get json_encode() working for the second table (bigger one) as well?

Comment: Does it throw any errors? Maybe you're hitting the max execution time?

Comment: There is no error thrown. Checking the length of the string with strlen() function returns 0 (so the string is empty).

Comment: Check your `memory limit`...

Comment: ini_get('memory_limit') returns that memory_limit = 75M. Can that be a problem with for example 949 rows as a result of a select query from a table with 50k rows?

Comment: Error reporting is on though? You get `0` on `strlen(json_encode($array))`?  Is `count($array)` returning a value? What does `$array` look like?

Comment: I already figured out that there is a JSON_ERROR_UTF8 responding. Which points do I have to check for correct utf8 encoding?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem: I had to change my whole encoding structure to UTF-8. So I changed:

- the database encoding to UTF-8 (in PhpMyAdmin)
- the table encondings to UTF-8 (in PhpMyAdmin)
- the connection encoding with `$connection->set_charset("utf8");`
- the url encoding in the java programm which fills the database (get & post data)